What should we do with all of these symfony tags?
I just posted a question about symfony. When looking for a version-specific tag, I saw I was the first to post question about version 7.x. I created it. Afterwards, I checked all existing tags about symfony.
They don't seem to be consistent. I found this post that proposed a pattern, which has been accepted and completed but it's no longer valid:

symfony3.x should be symfony-3.x or the x should be replaced. The tag's wiki mentions people should also use symfony3, but they can't as it's only an alias of symfony.
symfony5.4 should be symfony-5.4
Tags as symfony2.4, symfony3.4 and symfony4.2 always exists (even if they are aliases, they create confusion)
symfony4-voter should be symfony-voter as discussed here

What should we do? Should we remove minor versions tags to replace them by major versions?

If one really wanted to clean up, minor versions shouldn't exist. A tag for each major is enough... and frankly, even more than enough. I'd personally have a tag for Symfony < 2, and another for Symfony >= 2. And tags for components are fine, but versioned tags for components are not. But cleaning all this up ends in nothing, because they end up being created again and again. Probably, I have been guilty of creating at least one of those at some point in the past. Shame on me.

@yivi if most of people agree with you, and if someone remove alias for [tag:symfony2] to [tag:symfony] and [tag:symfony3] to [tag:symfony], I can do the most of the job

Seems like a mess. Not to make this too confusing, but I did part of this. I got rid of the symfonyX.X tags synonym stubs ([tag:symfony2.4], [tag:symfony3.4] and [tag:symfony4.2]) and renamed the tags missing the dash to include the dash [tag:symfony-5.4] and [tag:symfony-3.x]. Everything is now consistent with dashes at least. (Those synonyms can be put back at any time if needed.)

I can definitely remove the synonyms from symfony if that's what's best. Though the symfony2 -> symfony synonym was created in 2012 with 3943 renames. That's quite a longstanding synonym to remove lightly. I'd need a bit more input before separating out those tags.

I'm not across Symfony so bear with me if this is a silly suggestion, but I'm wondering if the version tags should just be [symfony-3], [symfony-4] etc? As in, why the .x?

Suggested title: We have a cacophony of symfony tags.

I made changed for tags[tag:symfony-4.3] and [tag:symfony-5.4], but synonym are already here. So yes it would be with pleasure if you remove them @HenryEcker

2 and 3 synonyms are now gone. It'd be easy to merge again if ever needed.

Thanks Henry ! I just see that [tag:symfony1] didn't had synonym for [tag:symfony], but version 2 and 3 did.

They should probably be ... decomposed :-)

As talked in comments, and very liked by people (and confirmed by moderator), here are changed that will be/are made:

Synonym for symfony2 and symfony3 to symfony have been removed.
For each sub versions, tags will be changed to global one (symfony) or to major version (as symfony1, symfony2 ...).
Some posts are wrongly tagged in general: no tag php even if needed, multiple subversions mentionned etc.

Actually, tags for Symfony 5, 6 et 7 are fine.
